# How to create a video from different subsets of media like images/texts etc

Tags: c#, javascript, html, facebook, video

I am trying to build a feature that is similar to facebook's recent timeline/profile video. Where in facebook creates a video that summarizes your timeline events in a very intuitive video. I am wondering how can we make a video out of custom images, texts and themese via code.

I write C#/JavaScript/HTML for living, it would be helpful if there is a library or API that would allow me to do this. If not any other language is fine I am willing to go that extra mile

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at ffmpeg. I don't know any .net api but even their windows command line client is powerful enough to script any video composing task.